# MySQL & NetBeans Integration issue

Tags: mysql, database, netbeans, installation

I am trying to get MySQL and NetBeans to work together but I am getting a very weird behavior. When I installed MySQL I gave it a password and noticed it had a database called "test". I created a table in it and ran successful queries against it.

Then I rebooted my Windows 7 machine, opened up NetBeans and tried to connect to the database using the stored password. Connection failed. However connecting with a blank password succeeds, but the "test" database is now gone!!

I had a previous version of MySQL, but uninstalled it and removed all folders I could find with mysql in it.

I installed NetBeans EE from scratch.

Installed MySQL server only and gave root a non-blank password.

Connected to it using pwd from above and used NetBeans tools to add table to "test" database (which was there by default). Note this was done during the same computer log-in session.

Did nothing else but rebooted the machine and tried to connect to MySQL from NetBeans and got password error. Connecting with blank password works, but "test" db (along with my table) is now gone.

I suspect the "test" db may have to do with temporary files/setup, but I am not sure and I really don't understand the password issue...

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try another program to test the connection to the database. (to isolate the problem MySQL/NB)

Comment: I can log on with MySQL workbench without password and the test database isn't there, so it doesn't seem to be NB. I can work around this since it only happens at install time, but I would like to know what's going on... I've seen the password issue multiple times since I help students set up.